# AWS RDS vs MySql database directly on EC2

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rds

I created MySql database directly on EC2 instance (I host there my web app and database), I didn't set up RDS. But my database constantly keep crashing. So now I want to use RDS.
How to integrate my existing databases on EC2 with RDS?

By integrate I mean simply how to migrate them to RDS that they stop crashing on EC2 instance. Do I have to remove them from EC2, stop mysqld service on EC2 and then create them from scratch on RDS and change database access configurations in my apps or is there simpler way?

Comment: What do you mean by "integrate"?

Comment: See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.AnySource.html.

Answer (score 0):

Unload your data from the SQL instance into CSVs. Put it into S3. Terminate your EC2 instance. Spin up RDS instance. `Load` data out of S3 into RDS. Job done.